# Automatic-Importing Scala packages/classes/object in IntelliJ

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I am using IntelliJ 2016.2.4 with SBT 0.13. In build.sbt I import breeze. However when I use something from breeze in one of my classes, IntelliJ does not offer me a fitting import. How do I configure IntelliJ to do that?

Comment: Have you installed the Scala plugin?

Comment: Yes (there is only one, right?) I have. I am able to compile my project.

Comment: Ok, now something is working... not sure what I changed. I have to observe if the issue returns.